# Eclipse does not show variable values on hover

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I remember, Eclipse was showing variable values during debug and on mouse hover. Unfortunately, currently it does not work for me. Instead of value, it shows FQN of the variable.

How to fix?

Comment: In Eclipse's Debug View (http://www.edu4java.com/_img/java/after-eclipse-debug-perspective.png), make sure your current thread and current class are selected.  Sometimes (on my system anyway) Eclipse focuses a *different* class or thread to what my breakpoint actually hit. Then I can't hover over the variables until I select the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a variable --> right click --> Whatch